# The difference between these vector notations

Tags: vectors

There is an equation, written in a book that I'm reading:

$$\textbf{I}(t) = \int \int \int_V \rho[(\textbf{r}\cdot\textbf{r}) \textbf{1} - \textbf{rr}] dV $$

with $\textbf{I}(t)$ is the moment-of-inertia tensor, $\rho$ the scalar density, $\textbf{1}$ the identity matrix and $\textbf{r}$ a position vector.

What is the difference between $\textbf{r}\cdot \textbf{r}$ and $\textbf{rr}$?

Surely if the vector $\textbf{r} = (x, y, z)$, then $\textbf{r}\cdot \textbf{r} =\begin{bmatrix}x & y & z \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y \\ z \end{bmatrix} =x^2+y^2+z^2$.

Similarly, $\textbf{rr} =  \begin{bmatrix}x & y & z \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y \\ z \end{bmatrix} $ as well?

We have one notation suggesting a dot product and the other standard matrix multiplication, but both are the same thing with vectors.

Comment: We may need more context to figure this out. Is the integrand a scalar, or a vector? What is the bold 1 with scalar coefficient $(r \cdot r)$? Does the $rr$ notation appear earlier in the text?

Comment: I've added some more details, or at least as much detail as the text gives me

Comment: My guess is this is the moment of inertia, which is a rank 2 tensor. Hence $\textbf{rr}$ is a tensorproduct, but that can be recast as the matrix product of the column vector with the row vector, whereas the inner product is row with column.

Comment: To keep the units right, rr must be a matrix too.

Comment: Ah, that would make sense. Yes you were right, I've included the details in the question

Comment: I think that $rr$ should properly be $rr^T$ (assuming $r$ is a column vector).

Comment: It is entirely possible the symbol didn't render - another way to recast your two products without matrix notation would be $$\mathbf{r}\cdot\mathbf{r}$$ and $$\mathbf{r}\otimes\mathbf{r}$$